# Как изменить TextView layout_main из другого класса?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как изменить TextView layout_main из другого класса?

Comment: Для этого надо в нужном месте иметь ссылку на нужный объект. Например, передав оную через конструктор или метод.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то так:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

//И прочие import

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView yourText;
    View yourLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        yourLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);
        yourText = yourLayout.findViewById(R.id.textId);
        yourText.setText("Text");

    }
}
```

Если TextView находится в layout_main (выбран для отображения через setContentView), то:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

//И прочие import

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView yourText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        yourText = findViewById(R.id.textId);
        yourText.setText("Text");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать паттерн MVP.
В классе работы с layout сделай функцию (в параметрах можешь указать строку например, которая будет отображаться в TextView), которая будет изменять текст TextView на тот, что передали параметром.
В твоем классе, откуда ты и хочешь менять TextView, вызываешь эту функцию, передавая в параметр нужное тебе сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
TextView textView;// Здесь textView выступает как переменная которой вы можете задавать любые параметры
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.  );//здесь вы пишете то Ид которое вы написали в main_layout.xml  на вашем textView в строке  android:id="@+id/Ваш ИД"
дальше играетесь с переменой как хотите
        textView.setText("Вводите текст");
        textView.setSize("Изменяете размер букв  желательно цифры писать и добавлять sp");
        textView.setStyle("Изменяете стиль на Жирным или курсивом");

}
```